# Can't get country from Reverse GeoCoding in some cases

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

[image: Screenshot of DB]

I have used google's reverse geo-coding to fetch administrative_area_level_1 , country and postal code.The issue is that in some cases I don't get the country(as you may see in the screenshot in case of California).
Here is my algorithm -

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        var components=results[1].address_components;
        console.log(components);

            for (var component=0;component<(components.length-1);component++){
                if(components[component].types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
                    var admin_area=components[component].long_name;
                }
                if(components[component].types[0]=="country"){
                    var country=components[component].long_name;
                }

                if(components[component].types[0]=="postal_code"){
                    var postal_code=components[component].long_name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming reverse Geocoding always returns the country, where is the fault ?

Comment: What about `results[0]`? Are you sure you get at least two results from geocoder?

Comment: Yes it does.Even if only one result is returned,that does not explain the reason for my problem, which is that, "I get the state but not the country".READ:[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#reverse-response)

Comment: One more question to help, can you share on which coordinates you cannot get country?

Comment: Not now, I was not saving the co-ordinates till now.